# How to convert type 'UnityEngine.Color32[ ]' to 'UnityEngine.Sprite'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019, zxing.net

I'm trying to generate a QR Code using ZXing.Net and at first I have the problem where the `.Save()` is not working because of an error CS1061. So, I scratched that idea then I tried to save `.Write()` as image then render it in unity but Unity returns an error:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Color32[]' to 'UnityEngine.Sprite'`

I tried using the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56676894/how-convert-type-unityengine-texture2d-to-unityengine-sprite/56680083#56680083) where they used `Sprite.Create()` as a solution but converted a Texture2D instead of a Color32[ ] but I wasn't able to confirm if the code worked for me since the code returns an error that:

`The type or namespace name 'Image' could not be found`

As I said, I wasn't able to find out if the code really worked or not. I don't know what caused the `namespace` error since the script I'm using is under the Image UI.

These are the codes I'm using:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using ZXing;
using ZXing.QrCode;
using System.Drawing;

public class SampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Texture2D myTexture;
    Sprite mySprite;
    Image myImage;

    void Main()
    {
        var qrWriter = new BarcodeWriter();
        qrWriter.Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE;

        this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = qrWriter.Write("text");
    }

    public void FooBar()
    {
        mySprite = Sprite.Create(myTexture, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, myTexture.width, myTexture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);
        myImage.sprite = mySprite;
    }

    void Start()
    {
        FooBar();
        Main();
    }
```

I still haven't tested this code since the errors must first be resolved before running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first

> The type or namespace name 'Image' could not be found

is fixed by adding the according namespace

```
using UnityEngine.UI;
```

at the top of your file.

---

The exception

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'UnityEngine.Color32[]' to 'UnityEngine.Sprite'

Can't simply be "fixed". It is as the exception tells you: You can't implicitly convert between those types .. not even explicitly.

```
 qrWriter.Write("text");
```

returns the `Color32[]`.

---

What you can try to do is creating a Texture using this color information **BUT** you will allways have to know the **pixel dimensions** of the target texture.

Then you can use [`Texture2D.SetPixels32`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.SetPixels32.html) like

```
var texture = new Texture2D(HIGHT, WIDTH);
texture.SetPixels32(qrWriter.Write("text"));
texture.Apply();
this.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0,0, texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.one * 0.5f, 100);
```

---

Possible that you also will actively have to pass in the `EncodingOptions` in order to set the desired pixel dimensions as shown in [this blog](http://mihakrajnc.com/generating-barcodes-in-unity-with-zxing/):

> ```
> using ZXing.Common;
>
> ...
>
> BarcodeWriter qrWriter = new BarcodeWriter
> {
>     Format = BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,
>     Options = new EncodingOptions
>     {
>         Height = height,
>         Width = width
>     }
> };
> Color32[] pixels = qrWriter.Write("text");
> Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(width, height);
> texture.SetPixels32(pixels);
> texture.Apply();
> ```

there you can also find some more useful information about threading and scaling of the texture etc.

Comment: A couple of things went wrong when I tried to use the code that you suggested. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/i74CTki)'s the script

Comment: why is `generateQR` not a `void` but a `Bitmap`? And why doesn't it return anything? You probably wanted to return the `texture` so make it `Texture2D`. For the `Rect` I missed a `)` after `texture.height`, my bad. The [`EncodingOptions`](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/ZXing.Common/EncodingOptions/-/php-encodingoptions-class-examples.html) is part of `ZXing.Common` so add `using ZXing.Common` to the top

Answer (score 0):

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    WebCamTexture webcamTexture;
    Color32[] data;
    public UIScreen screen;
    int HEIGHT, WIDTH;

    void Start()
    {
        // Start web cam feed
        webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
        webcamTexture.Play();
        HEIGHT = webcamTexture.height;
        WIDTH = webcamTexture.width;
        data = new Color32[WIDTH * HEIGHT];
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (webcamTexture.didUpdateThisFrame)
        {
            webcamTexture.GetPixels32(data);
            var texture = new Texture2D(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            texture.SetPixels32(data);
            texture.Apply();
            screen.imageUI.sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.one * 0.5f, 100);
        }
    }
}
```

`incase if anyone needs the entire code to convert and show webcam to imageUI/sprite`
`screen.imageUI is just the Image ui element in canvas`